# How to insert a HTML file template in Node for emails

Tags: node.js, express, html-email, lodash

I'd like to insert an HTML file template to be used in an email sent with node.

When I use the code below, I get this error...

> `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!doctype html>`

Any suggestions?

```
var template = require('../../views/email-template.js');
var htmlAll = _.template(template)(contactinfo[0]);
var data = {
   from: company@example.com,
   to: email,
   subject: 'Your Order Confirmation',
   html: htmlAll
```

email-template.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Email</title>
   <style media="all" type="text/css">

// . . .

    <table>
     // . . . 

          <td><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>
           <br><%= company %>
           <br><%= address %>
           <br><%= city %>, <%= state.code %> <%= zip %>
           <br><%= email %>
           <br><%= phone %>
          </td>
       </tr>

     </table>
  // . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't require non-javascript files via nodejs `require`

Use `fs` module

```
  var fs = require('fs')
  var template = fs.readFileSync('../../views/email-template.js').toString();
  var htmlAll = _.template(template)(contactinfo[0]);
```

it's better to cache `fs.readFileSync` result for continious use